# How to set and check if a particular bit is set?

Tags: scala

I have a object like this:

```
object PermissionMask {
  val canLogin = 1
  val canAbc   = 2
  val canDef   = 4
  val canGhi   = 8
}
```

I have a property of type INT that will hold the permission values.

How can I check if the permission is set?

```
   def canLogin: Boolean = 
     permissions & PermissionMask.canLog == ???
```

How can I OR them together to set all the permissions?

```
   permissions = PermissionMask.canLogin | PermissionMask.canAbc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check `canLogin` - all you have to do is compare the result to zero - if user can login, the result will be positive:

```
def canLogin: Boolean = (permissions & PermissionMask.canLogin) > 0
```

To create an "all permissions" value - well, yes, you started it correctly:

```
val permissions =  PermissionMask.canAbc | 
     PermissionMask.canAbc | 
     PermissionMask.canDef | 
     PermissionMask.canGhi
```